# How can I add a collection using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

I'm new to Blender. Tutorial information as recent as January this year appears to be out of date and I can't figure out how to create a new collection and add an object to it. The most recent relevant question I could [find](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/why-does-adding-an-object-to-a-collection-with-python-not-remove-it-from-its-old) suggests this:

```
bus_collection = ops.collection.new(name="BusRoutes")
context.scene.collection.children.link(bus_collection)
```

and apparently at least needs to be changed to this:

```
bus_collection = ops.collection.create(name="BusRoutes")
etc.
```

which throws the error:

```
TypeError: CollectionChildren.link(): error with argument 1, "child" -  Function.child expected a Collection type, not set
```

The [API entry](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.collection.html) for Collection operators is beyond sparse, and I'm not even sure what *Add the object to an object collection that contains the active object* even means.

May I ask someone to give me a minimal Blender 2.83 Python example of how to create a named collection and add an object to it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [`BlendDataCollections.new(name)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataCollections.html#bpy.types.BlendDataCollections.new)

Recommend use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> D.collections.new(
new()
BlendDataCollections.new(name)
Add a new collection to the main database
...

>>> my_coll = D.collections.new("MyCollection")
>>> C.scene.collection.children.link(my_coll)
```

Demo on how to create a new collection and add the default cube using [`CollectionObjects.link(object)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionObjects.html#bpy.types.CollectionObjects.link):

```
import bpy

# New Collection
my_coll = bpy.data.collections.new("MyCollection")

# Add collection to scene collection
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(my_coll)

# Get cube object
obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Cube")

if obj:
    # Link the cube 
    my_coll.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply - works. Thanks also for the console tip.

Comment: On reflection: what is the difference between "ops.collection.create(name="BusRoutes")" and "data.collections.new("BusRoutes")"?

Comment: Cool @Richard That's the high level call (for the user) and always requires a certain context eg. the outliner, an object in selection or what not, related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops

Comment: @Richard Notice this answer matches method used in question link.  A simple test print will confirm Operators return a status set, for example `{'FINISHED}` or `{'CANCELLED'}`  indicating the success  of the  "operation", not a reference to a newly created instance.  The error message in question reflects this..  Changes made by operators are reflected in context. When successfully run  the operator `bpy.ops.collection.create(name="Foo")` the newly created collection will contain the selected objects.  It is not however linked to the context scene or given context.